# Java operators performance arithmetic vs bitwise

Tags: java, performance, operators

In repetitive arithmetic operations where performance really matters, do bitwise operators have a positive or negative impact on performance? I tried to Google it but couldn't get a definitive answer.

For example should i use this:

```
int s = 15 << 4;
```

or this:

```
int s = 15 * 16;
```

to improve the performance of my application.

Also does [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) correlate with performance?

Comment: You shouldn't try to micro-optimize at all.

Comment: Please don't downvote well-written questions.

Comment: The best version would be `int s = 240;` :P (but the compiler will write that anyway).

Comment: @This is just a simple example for the sake of the question, i'm using a much complicated equations that use multiple bitwise operators.

Comment: @Tom: Perhaps not. There are instances where your code is easier to read if you "decompose" a constant. E.g. `seconds_in_day = 24 * 60 * 60`

Comment: If you were writing assembly, it would be your responsibility to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if these operations are not [compile-time constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) (for example `n << 4`), the virtual machine would select the faster implementation during the JIT compilation, so you can write in either way which is most readable for you. The performance will be the same.

Here's [the C++ code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/opto/mulnode.cpp#l197) of HotSpot JVM C2 JIT compiler which replaces multiplication to power-of-two with the left shift. A little below you may find more optimizations for some constants (like replacing `n * 12` with `(n << 3) + (n << 2)`).

Comment: (Not really relevant here as we're in the Java tag, *but* you have to be *very* careful with the left shift in C++, particularly with signed types.)

Answer (score 4):

In this case you could use either.

Both are compile-time evaluable constant expressions so the *compiler* will perform the operation. So the runtime will not be impacted at all.

If you had contrived an example that was only evaluable at runtime, then it would have been harder to say, but if I were you I'd trust the compiler in any case. Always use the appropriate operator for your task so bugs don't creep in. You can always profile performance.

Answer (score 3):

This code

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 15 << 4;
        int b = 15 * 16;
    }
}
```

is compiled to

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: sipush        240
       3: istore_1
       4: sipush        240
       7: istore_2
       8: return
```